# Extract 2D-image patches for training image and mask used in Semantic Segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I was wondering as to what would be my best approach to this problem. I have a 6000-by-6000 image with a 6000-by-6000 mask. I wanted to crop the image into several sub-images before training and came across [Extract_Patches_2d](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d) in Scikit learn. Looks like the tool to get the job done but I have one issue. If I run this on a single image, how can I be sure that it will use the same patch as a blueprint for the image mask as well ?